# Can sideways weightlifting be dangerous?

Tags: injury

I used to weight lifts sideways, which means I bent sideways while carrying a dumbbell in both of my hands. Naturally this created tension in both sides of my waist, and helped developed muscles there, but at the same time it created a temporary S-shape at the lower back.

Can this cause scoliosis by any chance?

PS In terms of physical injury, does the absence of pain or other symptoms able to be sensed, indicate the absence of injury?

Answer (score 4):

No, [dumbbell side bends](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Obliques/DBSideBend) are not inherently dangerous or injurious, but they are usually performed with a dumbbell only in one hand (then changing hands to train the other side). If you have a dumbbell in both hands, then the two weights will mostly cancel each other out, as when you lean to the side, one weight is raised while the other weight is lowered.

Comment: I agree with @david that doing a side bend with a dumbell in each hand is pointless.  More than that, it has to go on the list of the ten dumbest things you see in the gym. The logic might be that if one dumbell is good, then two dumbells are better.  But the logic doesn't really work.